# Is it possible to have Multiple String_Agg Columns with Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

I have the following table of Event Registrations. In the table, Muti-day events are recorded as an individual record for each registered date.  In addition, if a date is full, the date can still be registered for, as a Waitlisted Date.  I am trying to create a single record from the record in the table below where the dates are string aggregated. The table shown below, as well as several related tables are more complex than this, but I simplified for the sake of an example.

EventAssignments Table

```
+--------+---------+----------+--------+------------+
| UserID | EventID | AssignID | DateID | WaitListed |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+------------+
|      1 |      19 |       14 |     67 |          0 |
|      1 |      19 |       14 |     68 |          0 |
|      1 |      19 |       14 |     69 |          1 |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+------------+
```

EventDates Table

```
+--------+-------------------------+---------+------------+
| DateID |        EventDate        | EventID | DateTypeID |
+--------+-------------------------+---------+------------+
|     65 | 2019-03-20 00:00:00.000 |      19 |          1 |
|     66 | 2019-03-21 00:00:00.000 |      19 |          1 |
|     67 | 2019-03-22 00:00:00.000 |      19 |          2 |
|     68 | 2019-03-23 00:00:00.000 |      19 |          2 |
|     69 | 2019-03-24 00:00:00.000 |      19 |          2 |
|     70 | 2019-03-25 00:00:00.000 |      19 |          3 |
+--------+-------------------------+---------+------------+
```

The desired query results should look like this:

```
+--------+---------+----------+----------------------------+---------------+
| UserID | EventID | AssignID |      RegisteredDates       | WaitListDates |
+--------+---------+----------+----------------------------+---------------+
|      1 |      19 |       14 | 03/22/2019<br />03/23/2019 | 03/24/2019    |
+--------+---------+----------+----------------------------+---------------+
```

I was thinking that I needed some logic, so I tried to implement the use of CASE, as show below.  The results however still show as two records. the first record for regular dates, and the second for wait listed dates

```
SELECT a.UserID, a.EventID, a.AssignID, 
(CASE WHEN a.WaitListed = 'false' 
    THEN STRING_AGG(CONVERT(varchar, d.EventDate, 101), '<br />') END) AS RegDates, 
(CASE WHEN a.WaitListed = 'true' 
    THEN STRING_AGG(CONVERT(varchar, d.EventDate, 101), '<br />') END) AS WaitListDates
FROM dbo.EventAssignments AS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.EventDates AS d ON a.DateID = d.DateID
GROUP BY a.UserID, a.EventID, a.WaitListed, a.AssignID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT a.UserID, 
       a.EventID, 
       a.AssignID, 
STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN a.WaitListed = 'false' 
    THEN CONVERT(varchar, d.EventDate, 101) END, '<br />') AS RegDates, 
STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN a.WaitListed = 'true' 
    THEN CONVERT(varchar, d.EventDate, 101) END, '<br />') AS WaitListDates
FROM dbo.EventAssignments AS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.EventDates AS d 
  ON a.DateID = d.DateID
GROUP BY a.UserID, a.EventID, a.AssignID
```

Result:

```
UserID  EventID AssignID    RegDates                    WaitListDates
1       19      14          03/22/2019<br />03/23/2019  03/24/2019
```

Comment: So last night I took a different approach, and ran a subquery to return WaitListedDates from within the main query that returns RegDates. Although I did find a solution to my own question, I am awarding you the Accepted Answer, as it corrected the problem with my original post, and is likely the more performant code. –

Answer (score 0):

My fault for missing the consecutive `<br />` in the result.

Can you try this one, using recursive CTE?
It may require the concat operator to be replaced as well as the `ISNULL` but I wasn't perfectly sure about your DBMS...

```
WITH OrderedDates AS (
SELECT a.UserID, a.EventID, a.AssignID, a.WaitListed, CONVERT(varchar, d.EventDate, 101)                AS strEventDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY a.UserID, a.EventID, a.AssignID, a.WaitListed ORDER BY d.EventDate) AS EventDateOrder,
    COUNT(*)     OVER (Partition BY a.UserID, a.EventID, a.AssignID, a.WaitListed)                      AS EventDateCount
FROM EventAssignments AS a 
INNER JOIN EventDates AS d ON a.DateID = d.DateID
), ConcatDates AS (
    SELECT UserID, EventID, AssignID, WaitListed, EventDateOrder, EventDateCount, strEventDate
    FROM OrderedDates
    WHERE EventDateOrder = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT OD.UserID, OD.EventID, OD.AssignID, OD.WaitListed, OD.EventDateOrder, OD.EventDateCount, CD.strEventDate + '<br />' + OD.strEventDate
    FROM OrderedDates OD
    JOIN ConcatDates CD on OD.UserID = CD.UserID AND OD.EventID = CD.EventID AND OD.AssignID = CD.AssignID AND OD.WaitListed = CD.WaitListed AND OD.EventDateOrder = CD.EventDateOrder + 1
)
SELECT ISNULL(CD1.UserID, CD2.UserID), ISNULL(CD1.EventID, CD2.EventID), ISNULL(CD1.AssignID, CD2.AssignID), CD1.strEventDate, CD2.strEventDate
FROM            (SELECT * FROM ConcatDates WHERE EventDateCOunt = EventDateOrder AND WaitListed = 'false') CD1
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ConcatDates WHERE EventDateCOunt = EventDateOrder AND WaitListed = 'true' ) CD2 ON CD1.UserID = CD2.UserID AND CD1.EventID = CD2.EventID AND CD1.AssignID = CD2.AssignID
```

Comment: You should always have a length when using `varchar()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, You are absolutely correct. Just trying to get the logic to work before I worried about the other details.

Comment: @Lau, The answer does create one record as desired, but it adds additional unwanted <br /> tags before and after some dates in both RegDated and WaitlistDates columns.  
  
Reg Dates  
03/22/2019<br />03/23/2019<br /><br />03/25/2019  
  
WaitListedDates
<br /><br />03/24/2019<br />  
  
I did add an extra date when testing.

Comment: The solution does not need to use CASE, it can use any other methods that will work.  I just used CASE as it is in my comfort zone.

Comment: I think I would surround the string_agg with a regexp_replace then. Something like `regexp_replace( string_agg(...), '(<br />)+', '<br>')`. There may be a need for some characters to be escaped though ...

Comment: Lau, Thank you for your contributions and time.